# how highlight menuItem?

Tags: javascript, css, primefaces

I do a type of menu called "MenuBar" on jsf, which me refresh the page when clicking each menu type.

This is the Menu:

```
<h:form id="menuForm">
            <p:messages id="messages"/>
            <p:menubar styleClass="menuPrincipal" id="menuBar">
                <p:menuitem value="Inicio" url="/Inicio.xhtml" 
                     icon="ui-icon-home" styleClass="scroll" />
                <p:menuitem value="Agregar Excepciones" styleClass="scroll"
                    url="/ExcepcionNuevo.xhtml" 
                    icon="ui-icon-plusthick" />
            </p:menubar>
</h:form>
```

I made a function in js, to highlight the menuItem but when clicking me highlight the menuItem "Inicio" and  the other options when you click not me you highlight.

this is function:

```js
$(function() {

 $("a[href='/ScoreExcepciones/Inicio.xhtml']").addClass("active");
 $("a.scroll ").click(function() {
  $("a.scroll").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
 });
});
```

Comment: Please edit your original question instead of commenting. Thx.